# Two players drawing balls from an urn until the first red ball is selected

Tags: probability

[image]

My try:

$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{1}} + \frac{\binom{7}{2} \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} + \frac{\binom{7}{4} \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{5}}+ 
\frac{\binom{7}{6} \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{7}} $$

Another approach:

$$\frac{3}{10} +\frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 3}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8} + \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6} + \frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}  $$

What is the correct approach ?

Comment: The first approach is incorrect because second terms onwards, it does not ensure that $A$ is drawing the red ball and in the last pick.

Comment: So if the question would be: Player A and B draw without looking at the balls and then for $i = 1,2,3,4,5$ when they drawn a certain number of balls, they look what they got the first approach would be correct? @MathLover

Comment: The second term of "my try" gives the probability that exactly one red ball is drawn among the first three balls. But this includes a case where the red ball is drawn first, so it not disjoint from the event measured by the first term.

Comment: @VLC I am not sure I understand your point. Can you give an example? Also, see my answer and N.F.Taussig's answer and if any of them makes it clear where your mistake is and how your work can be fixed.

Comment: @MathLover I just wanted to say that if the question would be formulated in such a way that the order wouldn't matter, then the first try would be correct?

Comment: Yes if it was a different problem where the order did not matter in counting, that would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is correct.

To correct the first approach, you must multiply the probability that a red ball has not been received by one of the players in the first $k - 1$ rounds by the probability that player $A$ receives the ball during the $k$th round.

$$\Pr(A~\text{selects first red ball}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{10}{1}} + \frac{\dbinom{7}{2}}{\dbinom{10}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{8}{1}} + \frac{\dbinom{7}{4}}{\dbinom{10}{4}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{6}{1}} + \frac{\dbinom{7}{6}}{\dbinom{10}{6}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dbinom{4}{1}}$$

As Math Lover indicated in the comments, the problem with your first approach is that you did not ensure that player $A$ took the first red ball during the last round, just that the first red ball was taken by the time player $A$ made a pick in the $k$th round.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach:

$ \small \displaystyle \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{1} + \binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{3} + \binom{7}{4} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{5} + $
$ \small \displaystyle \binom{7}{6} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{7}$

The mistake:

Take the second term for example. The numerator is number of ways of choosing $2$ black balls and $1$ red ball in $3$ picks and the red ball can be in any place. But you want the red ball in the third pick.

So one of the ways to fix your work is as follows:

$ \small \displaystyle \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{1} + \frac 13 \cdot \binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{3} + \frac 15 \cdot \binom{7}{4} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{5} + $
$ \small \displaystyle \frac 17 \cdot
\binom{7}{6} \cdot \binom{3}{1} / \binom{10}{7}$